# Select rows in df based on a column1 of df and latest date in column2

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in pandas with following layout:

```
  title       date  value1
0   ABC   6/2/2018    1900
1   ABC   6/1/2018    1000
2   ABC  5/29/2018     405
3   ABC  3/18/2018     300
4   ABC  3/17/2018      50
5   LMO   6/1/2018     100
6   LMO  5/30/2018      10
7   LMO  5/29/2018       1
```

I want to create `df2`. It will only contain rows of titles with latest date . I am new python and pandas therefore have to ask for help.

`df2`:

```
  title      date  value1
0   ABC  6/2/2018    1900
1   LMO  6/1/2018     100
```

Comment: Weclome to SO. Please take a moment to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples to see how to make a good reproducible pandas example. Images aren't helpful as we can't copy and paste them into sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
df[df.groupby('title').date.transform('max') == df['date']]
```

---

**df_new:**

```
    title   date        value1
0   ABC     2018-06-02  1900
5   LMO     2018-06-01  100
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort the data by date, group by title, and take first.

```
df.sort_values('date', ascending=False).groupby('title').first()
```